# DateTimePicker component, C++ Builder 6

Tags: datetimepicker, c++builder

What should I do to make it possible to enter a year with a keyboard in the marked window? Since only arrows are allowed by default, and it's not very convenient.

[image]

Comment: You can edit the date with your keyboard while it is **not expanded with the down button**. I do not know whether it can be modified to accept keyboard while expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TDateTimePicker` is just a thin wrapper for the standard Win32 [DTP control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/date-and-time-picker-control-reference). The standard DTP control simply does not support the functionality you are asking for. The Year can only be set using the arrows when the control is expanded. See [About Date and Time Picker Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/date-and-time-picker-controls) and [About Month Calendar Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-controls) for the types of keyboard input that are natively supported.

That being said, what you are asking for would require you to manually access the picker's drop-down [Month-Calendar control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-control-reference) (see [`DTN_DROPDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtn-dropdown) and [`DTM_GETMONTHCAL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-getmonthcal)) and then inject an [Up-Down control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/up-down-control-reference) directly into it where needed (not sure if there is an API to determine exactly where the calendar displays its current year, maybe [`MCM_GETCALENDARGRIDINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/mcm-getcalendargridinfo) or [`MCM_HITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/mcm-hittest) can be used for that?), and then subclass the calendar to handle the UD control's [`UDN_DELTAPOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/udn-deltapos) notification so you can [update the calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-setsystemtime) accordingly.

That is a LOT of work for very little gain.